# Inserting favorites into shell console

Tags: shell

Is there any tool/terminal emulator which supports that I can insert my 'favourites' like '2>/dev/null' or 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M' and so forth .. everywhere into the command line ?

I could not find any terminal emulator, or clipboard tool which has favorites ... :(

Thanks in advance.

Using aliases and bash functions are not enough flexible inserting these anywhere into the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save them as variables in your .bashrc (or if you use another shell, save them in its rc file).

For example: You can insert the line `var1='2>/dev/null'` in your .bashrc file.
Once you start the terminal and run any script which runs via bash (its shebang should refer to bash), you can refer to your variable by using `$var1`

Comment: It would be good if they can be copy pasted into the command line, but it is one step further, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a preferred invocation of `date`, you can set an alias:

```
alias date='date +%Y%m%d%H%M'
```

Now whenever you type `date`, you'll get the output of `date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.  You don't have to use the same name, e.g., you could use `alias date2=...`.

You can make that permanent by adding it to `~/.bashrc`.